# wrap is not defined D3.js text

Tags: d3.js, text

I have a strange issue related to text wrap.
Here is my code snippet.

```
// Add labels for the nodes
      nodeEnter.append('text')
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
          return 0//d.children || d._children ? 25 : -25;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
          // return d.data.name.length < 12 ? 5 : 0;
          if(d.data.name.length < 12)
            return 5;
          else if(d.data.name.length <= 22)
            return 0
          else if(d.data.name.length < 29)
           return -10
          else if(d.data.name.length < 37)
           return -10
          else
            return -15
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", 'middle')
        .text(function (d) { 
          return d.data.name;    
        })
        .call(wrap, 85); // This is just issue line...
```

As you can see at the bottom, its line occurs error like this.

```
oragnization_chart.html:433 Uncaught Reference Error: wrap is not defined
    at update (oragnization_chart.html:433)
```

When I comment this line, it works without any error, but I wanna wrap the long text.
I am using d3.v5 like this https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js
If you know the solution, help me soon.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

oh, I found the reason.
It's just my lack of knowledge about d3.
`wrap` was not supported function and needs to define by myself.
Here is my code sample.

```
function wrap(text, width) {

  text.each(function () {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
      tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");

    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Once I added this function, error's gone.
I hope this one will be helpful for the others.
Thanks